# The phrase "bundle of nerves"

Tags: usage

I heard one people saying to another:

> But now he is a **bundle of nerves**, he can not perform this particular task.

Does the phrase have any meaning at all? Is the phrase safe to use without hurting others feelings? What exactly is meaning of the phrase?

Answer (score 1):

It means that he is nervous.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bundle%20of%20nerves):

> : a very nervous person • I was a *bundle of nerves*.

Essentially, it's a combination of the two words, indicating that the person is "just a bunch of nerves."

I would not recommend saying anything like "You're just a bundle of nerves" to the person in question, however. Not unless you know them well and are sure they won't take it the wrong way.

---

It goes along with the other idiom of [*getting on someone's nerves*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-on-someone-s-nerves):

> [Macmillan]
>
> if someone or something gets on your nerves, they make you feel annoyed or nervous
>   *His constant humming is really beginning to get on my nerves.*

Comment: While I would agree that one should use caution before saying this to someone directly, I think it's also worth pointing out that it's **not** considered insulting or derogatory speech. In fact, if I wanted to say it as a disparaging remark, I'd probably change _bundle of nerves_ to [_nervous wreck_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nervous%20wreck), which still isn't necessarily a hurtful remark.

Comment: @J.R. Personally, if I were to choose between the two, I'd prefer to be called a nervous wreck. So, it seems subjective. But I don't think either is *disparaging*, just not what you necessarily want to hear.

Comment: The question has been answered but I've seen others confuse this phrase with some older usages of "nerves".  For example, maybe 50-60 years ago before anxiety & psychological disorders were able to be diagnosed to the state they are today, "a case of the nerves" was used to refer to a wide range of disorders. My wife had two elderly family members "with a case of the nerves/bad nerves" and they were eventually diagnosed with anxiety and schizophrenia.  You may not come across this usage of "nerves" today but you never know... :)